# grid pagination in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, grid

I have two divs

```
<div class="col-sm-10">5/6 in left</div><div class="col-sm-2">1/6 on right</div>
```

Can I do something to show col-sm-2 before (higher than) col-sm-10 if it's mobile/tablet view?

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to "pagination". See the docs on column ordering: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: Thank you for the links. You are right, 'pagination' was not the right word. `col-sm-2 col-sm-push-10` & `col-sm-10 col-sm-pull-2` and all works as I wanted